# text wrap of continuous text string

Tags: html

When I insert a continuous string of text in a fixed width "td", the text is not wrapping. Pls let me know why? Here are the links to the html pages.

[textstring with space](http://shivanand.in/tmp/textstring_withspace.html)
[textstring without space](http://shivanand.in/tmp/textstring_withoutspace.html)

Comment: What are you really asking? Do you want to know why the browsers behavior is such that it does not wrap the text, do you want to know what the behavior should be according to the specifications, or do you want a solution to a layout problem you have in one of your own projects?

Comment: Yes I want to know why the browsers behavior is such that it does not wrap the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if this might help:

```
<p style="width: 100em; word-wrap: break-word">ThisTexthasnoSpacesThisTexthasnoSpacesThisTexthasnoSpacesThisTexthasnoSpacesThisTexthasnoSpaces</p>
```

Unfortunately, that requires you to know how wide you want your column to be.

Comment: If you want the collumn to wrap, you probably know how wide it should be.

Comment: If I give the width in percentages it doesn't work. Does it take only pix, em, pt?

Comment: @Shivanand: Yes, as far as I know you can't specify the width of a <p> in percentages.

Answer (score 4):

You can add soft-hyphens: `&shy;`.
Put them within the long word.

Have a look at it with this:

```
This&shy;Texthasno&shy;SpacesThis&shy;Texthasno&shy;Spaces&shy;This&shy;Texthasno&shy;Spaces&shy;ThisText&shy;hasno&shy;Spaces&shy;This&shy;Texthasno&shy;Spaces
```

(deliberate over-use of `&shy;`)

This is the [hyphenator](http://code.google.com/p/hyphenator/), you might find it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that a lot of popular sites (like Facebook) will insert a space in your word if you make it too long. It's the common solution, so don't be afraid of doing it.